# How to Fix Site Can't Be Reached

Tags: networking

On my Windows 10 (Version 20H2) desktop, I receive a "This site can't be reached error" for one particular site (protectcovers.com). Oddly, I was able to connect earlier this week (even placed an order).

isitdownrightnow.com reports the site is UP.

I can ping the site:

```
C:\Users\Clayton>ping www.protectcovers.com

Pinging levj9m-protectstaging-magweb-do.nodes.hypernode.io [45.55.125.55] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 45.55.125.55: bytes=32 time=93ms TTL=46
Reply from 45.55.125.55: bytes=32 time=83ms TTL=46
Reply from 45.55.125.55: bytes=32 time=87ms TTL=46
Reply from 45.55.125.55: bytes=32 time=84ms TTL=46

Ping statistics for 45.55.125.55:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 83ms, Maximum = 93ms, Average = 86ms
```

I can nslookup the site:

```
C:\Users\Clayton>nslookup www.protectcovers.com
Server:  one.one.one.one
Address:  1.1.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    levj9m-protectstaging-magweb-do.nodes.hypernode.io
Address:  45.55.125.55
Aliases:  www.protectcovers.com
          protectstaging.hypernode.io
          magweb.protectstaging.hypernode.io
```

I can reach the site on my phone's 4G network (Verizon).

I have tried the following:

- used Chrome, Brave, and Edge browsers
- cleared all site data in all browsers
- ipconfig /flushdns
- nbtstat -RR
- netsh int ip reset
- netsh winsock reset
- turned off Windows Firewall and Anti-Virus
- rebooted and power cycled the cable modem (Comcast ISP)
- run Window Network Diagnostics
- verify no entry for site in windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts
- restarted desktop numerous times
- bypassed wifi router (erro) and directly connected desktop to cable modem.

Definitely appears to be a network issue. When I switch my phone to wifi, I can't reach the site. On my Windows 10 laptop (connected via wifi), I can't reach the site. Even an Ubuntu VM on my desktop can't reach the site.

I have done tracert:

```
C:\Users\Clayton>tracert www.protectcovers.com

Tracing route to levj9m-protectstaging-magweb-do.nodes.hypernode.io [45.55.125.55]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.4.1
  2    10 ms    10 ms     8 ms  96.120.0.145
  3     9 ms     9 ms    10 ms  po-301-1210-rur02.broadway.nm.albuq.comcast.net [69.139.207.117]
  4    10 ms    10 ms     9 ms  be-8-ar02.albuquerque.nm.albuq.comcast.net [162.151.130.121]
  5    32 ms    33 ms    35 ms  be-33654-cr02.losangeles.ca.ibone.comcast.net [68.86.166.65]
  6    34 ms    38 ms    33 ms  be-1302-cs03.losangeles.ca.ibone.comcast.net [96.110.39.225]
  7    32 ms    31 ms    31 ms  be-2301-pe01.losangeles.ca.ibone.comcast.net [96.110.44.106]
  8    33 ms    33 ms    36 ms  50.242.151.62
  9    40 ms    42 ms    39 ms  ae-11.r25.lsanca07.us.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.2.187]
 10    84 ms    77 ms   131 ms  ae-5.r25.asbnva02.us.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.3.188]
 11    87 ms    82 ms    82 ms  ae-4.r21.nwrknj03.us.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.6.117]
 12    82 ms    83 ms    81 ms  ae-11.r01.nycmny17.us.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.6.97]
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17    85 ms    85 ms    82 ms  45.55.125.55

Trace complete.
```

It times out as expected. However, even when I tracert another site (amazon.com) which opens normally, I see time outs occurring also:

```
C:\Users\Clayton>tracert www.amazon.com

Tracing route to d3ag4hukkh62yn.cloudfront.net [13.225.148.15]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.4.1
  2    13 ms    11 ms     9 ms  96.120.0.145
  3    24 ms    11 ms     9 ms  po-301-1209-rur01.broadway.nm.albuq.comcast.net [69.139.207.101]
  4    11 ms    17 ms    11 ms  be-8-ar01.albuquerque.nm.albuq.comcast.net [162.151.130.117]
  5    19 ms    21 ms    20 ms  be-36811-cs01.1601milehigh.co.ibone.comcast.net [96.110.44.17]
  6    17 ms    19 ms    18 ms  be-1114-cr14.1601milehigh.co.ibone.comcast.net [96.110.39.114]
  7    20 ms    21 ms    18 ms  be-301-cr14.champa.co.ibone.comcast.net [96.110.39.1]
  8    20 ms    22 ms    20 ms  be-1414-cs04.champa.co.ibone.comcast.net [96.110.37.253]
  9    20 ms    19 ms    20 ms  be-1412-cr12.champa.co.ibone.comcast.net [96.110.37.222]
 10    41 ms    42 ms    41 ms  be-303-cr11.sunnyvale.ca.ibone.comcast.net [96.110.39.26]
 11    47 ms    77 ms    58 ms  be-1111-cs01.sunnyvale.ca.ibone.comcast.net [96.110.46.1]
 12    40 ms    49 ms    41 ms  be-1112-cr12.sunnyvale.ca.ibone.comcast.net [96.110.46.6]
 13    42 ms    42 ms    48 ms  be-304-cr01.9greatoaks.ca.ibone.comcast.net [96.110.37.182]
 14    46 ms    42 ms    41 ms  be-11525-cr02.losangeles.ca.ibone.comcast.net [68.86.84.149]
 15    57 ms    51 ms    43 ms  be-1202-cs02.losangeles.ca.ibone.comcast.net [96.110.39.205]
 16    39 ms    59 ms    42 ms  be-2202-pe02.losangeles.ca.ibone.comcast.net [96.110.44.118]
 17    48 ms    41 ms    40 ms  50.248.118.190
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25    42 ms    40 ms    41 ms  server-13-225-148-15.lax3.r.cloudfront.net [13.225.148.15]

Trace complete.
```

I'm stumped...

Comment: Sounds to me like your IP address is being blacklisted at the site. See if you can access it via a VPN or similar.

Comment: It's not unusual you can't do a complete traceroute.  Those "request timed out" nodes are normal.

Comment: Interesting. Don't have VPN, however, I was able to reach the site (although slow) using a Tor window in Brave. So, what, do I contact the site to be removed from the blacklist?